# Executing HiveActivity on an existing EMR cluster (using workergroup) error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

This is error:

ActivityFailed:AmazonServiceException:AmazonElasticMapReduce:AccessDeniedException

User: arn:aws:iam::833376745199:user/data_analytics is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:DescribeCluster (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 593d224c-7097-11e6-a574-fd5be6acde1b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the IAM user that you're using to start the task runner has the `elasticmapreduce:DescribeCluster` permission. Unless you want to apply a more restrictive policy to your task runner, an easy way to do this would be to attach the `AmazonEC2RoleForDataPipeline` to your IAM user.

Comment: Note that if you're not explicitly specifying AWS credentials when you start the task runner, then it will assume the role that is used by the EC2 instance. If this is how you're starting the task runner, then the easiest fix is to specify that the EC2 instance should use the DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole.